# How to review and modfiy changes before submitting, using IntelliJ's perforce integration?

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce

When I use the Perforce integration to submit changes, I can view the diffs for each file using the dialog pictured below. However, I am unable to modify my source file from this dialog. If I want to do something like remove an unused import, I have to close the perforce dialog, edit the source, and relaunch the dialog.

Is there a better workflow which would allow me to review and modify changes, without closing and relaunching this dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to modify files using the diff in the commit dialog, modifications are just locked by default to avoid accidental changes.

All you need to do is to click the Lock icon in the toolbar above the diff.
This one:
[image: Unlock modification]